# How i calculate mean for list using for loop?

Tags: list-manipulation

Here I hava a nested list as follow

```
a = {{1, 2, 3},{2, 1,2},{1, 3, 2}};


For[i = 1, i < Length[a], i++, t=Mean[a[[i]]]]
```

But the result is not expected I get
2
But I want `{2,5/2,2}`

Comment: **I want to use loop and put results in list** this is what @tueda solution does. If you must use a loop, you can do `First@Last@Reap[Do[Sow[Mean[a[[n]]]],{n,1,Length@a}]]` but I think `Map[Mean,a]` is much better and more clear. (which is another way to write `Mean /@ a`. The reason your loop did not work is because you were overwriting `t` each time in the loop, and only the last value of `t` survived.

Comment: Very down to earth way of doing it (wrong from the point of view of MMA coding) 
`t = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[a], i++,
 AppendTo[t, Mean[a[[i]]]]
 ]`

Comment: thanks more Daniel Binosi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want `{2,5/3,2}`? This can be obtained by `Mean /@ a`.

Comment: I want to use loop and put results in list

Answer (score 5):

Rule number one of WL: [forget that `For` exists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica). It's never a good way to do things in Mathamatica. This is what you want to do:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3},{2, 1,2},{1, 3, 2}};
t = Map[Mean, a];

t
```

> {2, 5/3, 2}

If you want a more general method for computing the mean of rows/columns, look at `ArrayReduce`:

```
ArrayReduce[Mean, a, 1] (* average over rows, giving you column means *)
ArrayReduce[Mean, a, 2] (* average over columns, giving you row means *)
```

> {4/3, 2, 7/3}

> {2, 5/3, 2}